# "Parallel sorting using Parallel.For does not work correctly"

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I`m doing a project where I have to parallel some sorting algorythms and compare parallel results to sequential. I try to parallelise Insertion sort using Parallel.For loop, but it does not work correctly. First part of array is sorted great and another part starts to sort array again from wrong index.

```
        Parallel.For(1, myarray.Length, x =>
        {

                int cur = myarray[x];
                int j = x;

                while (j > 0 && cur < myarray[j - 1])
                {
                    myarray[j] = myarray[j - 1];
                    j--;
                }
                myarray[j] = cur;                        
        }
```

The part of my result for 500 random elements from [0-1000] where mistake exist:

...... 992 992 995 997 224 225 228 228 231 233 234 235 237 ......

It is still 500 elements but a part of them are moved to the end.
So it works but some thread try to sort it again from some index I guess. How can I fix it?

Comment: I`ve tried to use "lock" constructions for all the loop but this not help.

Comment: It's not possible to parallelize insertion sort, as whole array would be mutated concurrently, https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-implement-an-insertion-sort-using-CUDA-parallel . Simply: do not share mutable state between threads

Comment: Use PLinq As parallel, that does help in parallel sorting of data

Comment: In general avoid using a shared data inside `Parallel.ForXXX` delegates. The `Parallel` methods are purposed for the data parallelism and using a shared data inside them can easily eliminate all advantages of these methods as such operations require synchronization.